# Copying WhatsApp chat history to new Android

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

There have been many questions asked and answered on this topic but unfortunately I've not found one that addresses my issue.
I have read that to transfer the WhatsApp chat history to a new phone it is necessary to first back up the chat history from the old phone (before removing the SIM) to Google Drive. Unfortunately I didn't do this. I moved the SIM from my old to the new, installed WhatsApp and registered it with the old number, so losing all my chat history.

I assume that my chat history is still on my old phone but if I run it with a different SIM, WhatsApp presents me with the welcome screen and I have no way of accessing my chat history (I have not tried registering WhatsApp on the old phone with an new number). So I now have a chat history on both my old and new phones.

Is there any way to access the chat history from the old phone and combine it with that on the new phone.

Suppose I temporarily move my original SIM back to my old phone and get WhatsApp running again with the old number, will my chat history be restored? If so, I am thinking I could then do the Backup to Google Drive and then somehow combine the two histories on the new phone

Comment: use your old phone in flight mode, it won't care about SIM card for a while

Answer (score 0):

There is no way intended to combine different accounts. There is however unofficial solution for advanced users. Unfortunately I don't use WhatsApp and never used any of this tools, so I can give link-only answer only.

1. However, first step is get Legacy WhatsApp installed without uninstalling app data. This can probably be achieved with

   ```
   adb uninstall -k com.whatsapp
   adb install -r -d WhatsApp-2.11.431.apk
   ```

   This will give you the availbility to create adb `backup.ab` and extract the database with `abe.jar` Android backup extractor without rooting the device.

   This of course must repeated for second account, too. Refer to following link for details, troubleshooting and support.
   [[Tool] WhatsApp Key/DB Extractor | CRYPT6-12 | NON-ROOT | UPDATED OCTOBER 2016](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2770982)
2. second step is merge databases into one account.
   [[TOOL] Merjapp - merge whatsapp databases](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2896496)
3. third step merged database must re-packed and restored to device

Comment: links provided are very old and might not work with recent database version. In case you succeed in step 1 this answer will be improved/extended in step 3 by me

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's fairly simple. When you go to reset your phone, you are able to save your data for apps. After you do the reset, your phone will ask you if you want to restore all of your applications and all of your data. I've done it many times and it has always saved my data.

Comment: *I've done it many times and it has always saved my data.* -- that's good to know, but you didn't explicitly mention whether your suggested solution proved useful for migrating Whatsapp's chat history to a new phone. The question is about migrating chat history of Whatsapp per se, so a solution even if it is a generic approach, ought to address it. Can you [edit] and clarify to what extent your solution worked for migrating data of Whatsapp from one phone to another?